# App_Offline -> 404 Error

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, app-offline.htm

By simply putting a file named app_offline.htm in the root directory of your site, ASP.NET will serve the app_offline.htm file, instead of the requested page. I recently employed this feature for probably the first time.  I put the app_offline.htm file on the site, and pulled up my site in Firefox.  The contents of app_offline.htm displayed as expected. However, if I were to pull my site in IE, I would get a Page Not Found error that appeared as though my entire site did not exist. The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 – IIS 7.5
What ist he problem, how can i fix this? I hope somebody can help me,

Thanks Horst

Answer (score 4):

How big (in **bytes**) is your `app_offline.htm` ?

If I remember correctly, for IE, there was a quirk that required this file to be a certain minimum size to be recognized (512 bytes).

Read more on Scott Gu's blog about this: [App_Offline.htm and working around the IE Friendly Errors feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/App_5F00_Offline.htm-and-working-around-the-_2200_IE-Friendly-Errors_2200_-feature.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.
I made a new site with this content:
The site has 448Bytes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Errorpage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://error/index.html" >
</head>
 <body>
        <script language="javascript" >
         window.location = "http://error/index.html";
       </script>
 !!Errorpage!!
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks,
Horst